# Is it possible to implement a UITableView overlay on top of the main UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically, I have a UITableView, and there's a cell which contains a textbox. I want to implement an overlay table view that pop up to show the typeahead results.

Answer (score 1):

So, to be very objective and answer your question, yes, yes you can.